# Using a trigger to make a table read-only in DB2

Tags: db2, database-trigger

I need to make a table read-only in DB2.

Even though one option is to revoke insert, update, and delete privileges, I decided not do try this one since it would still allow the DBAs to change data in the table. Also I would like to show a nice clear error message, if possible.

Therefore, I wanted to explore the option of a DB2 trigger, but I'm afraid I'm far from an expert on the matter. When I try to create it I get an error.

At this point I've tried a myriad of variants but can't make it work. Here's the DDL:

```
create table employee_state (
  id int primary key not null,
  description varchar(40) not null
);

insert into employee_state (id, description) values (1, 'Applying');
insert into employee_state (id, description) values (2, 'Rejected');
insert into employee_state (id, description) values (3, 'Active');
insert into employee_state (id, description) values (4, 'Inactive');

create trigger employee_state_read_only 
  before delete on employee_state for each statement
begin
  raise_error(-20001, 
    'Delete operation not allowed on read-only table "employee_state".');
end//

DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=raise_error;ach statement
begin
;RETURN, DRIVER=4.21.29
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are worried about DBAs being able to modify your data, creating a trigger won't have any effect.  You need to implement proper permissions on the table, and perhaps implement separation of duties (i.e. have someone other than DBAs managing permissions).

Comment: `RAISE_ERROR()` is a function, and as such it must be invoked from an appropriate context, such as assignment. See this [example in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000839.html)

Comment: Thanks, I realized this after I wrote this question. Now I see the `raise_error` function can be quite useful; there's one case last year I could have used it to stop a select if the parameters were off limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use `SIGNAL` `SQLSTATE` with a custom message.

```
CREATE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_STATE_READ_ONLY 
BEFORE DELETE ON EMPLOYEE_STATE FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (1=1)
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '80001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'READ ONLY';
  END
```

Then on delete attempt  it will throw errors like `SQL0723 - SQL trigger EMPLOYEE_STATE_READ_ONLY in GLTCUAT failed with SQLCODE -438 SQLSTATE 80001.`

Comment: One question (not really a big deal, just being unnecessarily perfectionist): If I try `delete from employee_state where id = 5` it doesn't fail, since there's no id = 5. Is it possible to apply the trigger the the statement instead of "each row"?

Comment: No, the activation time for "FOR EACH STATEMENT" is only "AFTER" so it can't be applied here as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

A single trigger can cover all three cases. E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_STATE_READ_ONLY 
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE_STATE
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '80001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'READ ONLY'; END
```

of course a DBA could drop the trigger, make a change to the table and add the trigger again..

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about DBAs being able to modify your data, creating a trigger won't solve your problem as DBAs would be able drop the trigger, too (h/t @p-vernon).

You should implement proper permissions on the table, and if you don't trust DBAs, implement separation of duties – i.e., have someone other than DBAs managing permissions (the "Security Administrator").

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually do trust the DBAs, What I'm concerned about is that by mistake they could inadvertently make changes to the table if they blindly run a script.